# No reply to UDP broadcast, only unicast

Tags: java, android, udp, broadcast

In my Android app I'm sending a UDP broadcast to address 255.255.255.255, port 6400. I use the PC program Packet Sender to act as a UDP server that automatically sends a reply.

When I'm listening for this reply in the Android app, it never receives the reply. I can only receive the reply if I don't send the packet to 255.255.255.255, but to the specific IP address of the PC.

```
private String udpDestinationAddress = "255.255.255.255";
private int udpDestinationPort = 6400;
private int udpTimeoutMs = 5000;
private String udpData = "test";

DatagramSocket socket;
socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
socket.setSoTimeout(udpTimeoutMs);
socket.connect(InetAddress.getByName(udpDestinationAddress), udpDestinationPort);

// send part
byte[] data = udpData.getBytes();
int length = data.length;
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, length);               
socket.send(packet);

// receive part
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

// Initialize the packet
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

// Receive the packet
socket.receive(packet); // it timeouts here (if timeout=0, then it hangs here forever)

// Get the host IP
String hostIP = packet.getAddress().toString().replace("/", "");
```

In the PC program, I have set it to reply automatically (with another random string) to a packet on port 6400. This works quite well with other apps I've tested (various UDP test Android apps). However, my app cannot seem to get the reply.

I can only get a reply in my app when I've set `udpDestinationAddress` to the specific IP of the PC. I've also tried "192.168.5.255" (broadcast on my local subnet) instead of "255.255.255.255" - still doesn't work.

Comment: I've had this happen to me occasionally.  Sometimes the network drops the packet or won't forward it.  Depending on the network I run it on sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't

Comment: You network routers must allow multicast/broadcast for this to work...

Comment: @GermannArlington - The router already allows that.

Comment: Can I also assume that your IPs are on the same network? Did you try broadcasting repeatedly/frequently?

Comment: @GermannArlington - Of course.

Comment: The only explanation that I can think of is packet loss. Retransmit frequently to check that and if that does not help use wireshark (or something similar) to trace the packets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

Instead of binding the destination IP and port to the `socket`, I needed to bind it to the `packet` instead.

So, instead of:

```
socket.connect(InetAddress.getByName(udpDestinationAddress), udpDestinationPort);
...
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, length);
```

... use this instead:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(udpData.getBytes(), udpData.length(), addr, udpDestinationPort);
```